# Concurrent Environments in AppHarbor

Tags: hosting, appharbor

How can I host concurrent environments of a single application of on AppHarbor?

We are currently in development so a single environment of DEBUG is sufficient, with builds triggered from the develop branch.

Soon we will need a PROD environment, triggered by changes to the master branch (or perhaps manually).

How can I configure AppHarbor such that **both** the DEBUG & PROD environments are accessible at any given time for a single application?

With hostnames such as:

- http://debug-myapp.apphb.com
- http://prod-myapp.apphb.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now you will have to create two applications, one for your debug environment and one for your production environment. You can also set up the tracking branch for each application. Here is a [link](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments) where we describe how to manage environments.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this might be the route to take. As you say 'For now...' does this mean you are planning to add this feature to AppHarbor?

Comment: We're always looking at how to optimize this flow and we have some support for multiple environments per application in the data model. We think the current model is pretty good though, also because this neatly de-conflicts external resources like add-ons.

Comment: We've revisited this and moved all staging environment apps into app harbor. Here's my experience of doing so http://evolutionarydeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/appharbor-environment-management.html. All in all, very worthwhile!